Custom Text Input Is Not Updating
I have a custom text input component:
const model = defineModel({
    type: [Number, String],
});

   <input v-model="model" />

When I call it from a parent I do:
 <InputText v-model="day" />

But on the parent I now have a watcher...
const day = ref('');

watch(day, (newValue) => {
    day.value = newValue.toString().padStart(2, '0');
});

If you enter the same value twice, e.g. 1, delete and the 1 again, the first time it is padded, the second time it is not.
I've tried to debug this but both the parent and child think the model is 01. For some reason it's not updating.
The watcher is correct as a simple HTML input works.

Can you create a working example?
From what I see, the problem seems to be on the side of your input. The way the v-model trigger the event.
